# pgrouting download link not working

Tags: pgrouting

I am trying to download pgrouting but the download links are not working. I have tried many links but no link is working.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **pgRouting v2.x**:

As stated on http://www.postgis.net/windows_downloads :

*Winnie is currently down and is being rebuilt. For the time being use the released versions of PostGIS and **pgRouting** which are available both via **PostgreSQL EDB StackBuilder** and also on **PostGIS Windows** downloads — details in Released Versions column.*

For **pgRouting v1.x**:

Disable your antivirus/firewall for the download duration, if you have problems.

For other SO see https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting, also.